# Dependency Property Get and Set

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Hello Every One I Have This Dependency property How I Can Get The Value The Value Is set in XAML

```
     public static bool GetSuppressLinks(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(SuppressLinksProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSuppressLinks(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SuppressLinksProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SuppressLinksProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SuppressLinks",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(LinkTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

so When i Call The Get Method what i should pass for it :/ What is this object 
Thank you very Much.

Comment: You have declared an attached property, a special version of a dependency property, which is supposed to be set on instances of different classes derived from DependencyObject. Did you intend to do that?

Comment: No i Just Have It like that In My Class  Is There Any Way To get the Value Without The Object  ?

Comment: As different objects may have different values, how could this be possible?

Comment: You can only get the value of an attached property from an instance of DependencyObject or a derived class. An attached property is not a static property, although the get and set methods are static.